# How do you drop the intelligence/Australium?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I used to think this wasn't possible, but I think I saw someone simply drop the intelligence on the ground without using the Dead Ringer or running back to spawn or dying.

Is there a way to manually drop the intelligence/Australium in Team Fortress 2, and if so how?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, there is a way indeed. The key is by default is <kbd>L</kbd>.

You can find it in the keybinding screen as "Drop the briefcase" inside the "TEAM FORTRESS" group.

Comment: The command is bound to the L key by default.

Comment: The command is labeled "Drop the Briefcase" and Kevin is right, it is 'L' by default.